# Wiring Diagram Software for Open Source Projects

Tags: wiring, diagram, cad

So, obviously, there are plenty of CAD software options out there for hobbyists and open source hardware folks to do PCB schematic capture and layout.

However, I'm having a really hard time figuring out the best way to draw up wiring and connection diagrams for assemblies. Auto Cad is waaaay to expensive for hobby work, but I'd like something reasonably professional. The closest I've seen is qelectrotech, but the documentation is mostly French, and it was pretty rough to learn. It also doesn't do system level cable connection diagrams.

Is anyone aware of a reasonable way to do this without using something nasty like Visio? Maybe misuse of KiCad in some way or something?

Comment: Graphviz? Inkscape?

Comment: Those kind of fall into the vizio category. I *can* use those, but it'd be far better to use a proper CAD tool and have a nice drawing frame on without having to hack it together.

Comment: @Obi_Kwiet I did a search on sourceforge and [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/draftcable/?source=directory) popped up. Have you looked it over for your needs? (I have no idea how close it may come to your needs.) Also [Widi Cad](https://sourceforge.net/projects/widicad/?source=directory) came up, too.